# Java realtime audio FFT

Tags: java, arrays, audio, byte, buffer

My aim is to take in two channels of audio from a live source, perform some FFT analysis and display realtime graphs of the data.

So far I have researched and have gotten to the point where I can create a targetdataline from my audio interface with two channels of audio at a specified audioformat.  I have created a buffer for this stream of bytes, however I would like to treat each audio channel independently.  Do I need to split the stream as it writes to the buffer, and have two buffers?  Or do I need to split the buffer into different arrays to process?

```
    final AudioFormat format = getFormat();


        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) m.getLine(info);

        line.open(format);
        line.start();
        System.out.println("Line Started");
        Thread captureThread = new Thread(){

            int bufferSize = (int) (format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameRate() * format.getChannels());
            byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize / 5];

                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                while(running) {
                int numBytesRead = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                while (numBytesRead > 0) {
                    arraytoProcess = buffer;

                    Thread fftThread;
                    fftThread = new Thread(){
                        public void fftrun() {
                            try {

                                fftCalc();
                            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        };
                    };
                     while (numBytesRead == buffer.length){
                         fftThread.start();
                     }
                }
```

I am sure I have gone far wrong, however any pointers would help.  When I try running this at the moment I am aware that it takes too longer to complete the 'fftThread' than it takes for each pass of the buffer so I get an illegal thread state exception  (however it is currently getting all bytes (stereo channel) passed to this thread.  I have tried the good old search engines however things aren't overly clear on how to deal with accessing multiple channels of a TargetDataStream.

Comment: I would ignore stereo until you get working a single channel ... also I would simplify more to ignore any streaming aspect and get working a stand alone audio buffer to FFT then get your visualization working ... only then strap back on stereo however unless your input signal warrants it both channels will typically have very similar freq spectrum so collapsing multi channels into one should be fine ... and last plug your working stand alone code back into a streaming context

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The end result is not to measure a stereo source, but to measure a microphone input & a reference input from an audio interface to compute a dual fft. Unless I have misunderstood, I believe the two channels from my audio interface are streamed down one TargetDataLine from my interface so I need to separate these. I agree with trying to just do one for now to get it working, however for some reason I have a ‘getFormats()’ method to try all of the different formats available from a TargetDataLine &return the ones that are compatible, & there are no mono lines available